# MVC - disable roughly half the fields based on a user's permissions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

I have a view with roughly 50 fields on it.  I need to be able to set roughly half of these to disabled if the user is NOT an administrator.  What's the proper way to do this?  I assume there's a better way than simply doing the following 25 times?

```
    @if (User.IsInRole("Admin") == false)
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AssociateName, new {disabled = "true"})
    }
```

Comment: i see some better syntax where your viewmodal interact with user's role..by some attribute

Answer (score 4):

The proper way to do this would be to create two views, admin and non-admin, and then render the appropriate one once the role is determined.

Comment: If possible, you could extract just those 25 fields into a partial view, then only change the partial view, leaving the rest intact.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could simplify it to something like this:

```
@{
    bool isAdmin = User.IsInRole("Admin");
}

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AssociateName, isAdmin ? new { disabled = "disabled" } : new {})
```

Or you could create an editor template that does it for you:

```
@model string

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m User.IsInRole("Admin") ? new { disabled = "disabled" } : new {})
```

Model:

```
[UIHint("_MyEditorTemplate")]
public string MyProperty { get; set; }
```

Main view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyProperty)
```

Or you could conditionally render different views from your controller:

```
if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
    return View("AdminView", model);
}
else
{
    return View("UserView", model);
}
```

I would say all of these are valid approaches, depending on how much other flexibility you need (and whether you need to perform any other logic based on this in your GET action).

Bear in mind that, either way, you should be validating this on your POST before you act on any of the values posted, otherwise you are prone to model injection from non-Admin users.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things you should keep in mind.

- Input becomes disabled when attribute *disabled* exists on it. It
  does not matter whether you type `disabled="true"` or
  `disabled="false"` or `disabled` - in all these cases input will be
  disabled. This is the reason the first suggestion in the answer of
  @Ant_P won't work.
- Disabled inputs do not get submitted to the server in MVC. At all. A
  better way to handle this is to use attribute *readonly*
- It is very simple to change html and remove either *disabled* or
  *readonly* attribute. In which case user will be able to change values for the input. Consider security. It might be better to not render inputs at all.

You can create a custom html helper to accept whether the input is readonly or not similar to how it's done in [TwitterBootstrapMVC](https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/):

```
@Html.Bootstrap().TextBoxFor(x => x.Property).Readonly(User.IsInRole("Admin"))
```

Comment: Not rendering inputs makes absolutely no difference to security - if there is a model property, HTML can be injected.

Comment: True, though it makes less obvious that there is such a possibility